# How to execute python script in jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins

I am trying to build basic hello world application:

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      stage('Hello') {
         steps {
            echo 'Hello World'
            python E:/airflowtmp/hello.py

         }
      }
   }
}
```

When I execute it, it gives following error:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 8: Expected a step @ line 8, column 13.
               python E:/airflowtmp/hello.py
               ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:337)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Finished: FAILURE
```

How do I run a basic python application using Jenkins? I created a pipeline through dashboard and pasted python .py to the template. It successfully prints hello world but when I add python statement it generates the error.

Answer (score 1):

You should be wrapping the python execution within `sh` directive for it to work.

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
      stage('Hello') {
         steps {
            echo "Hello World"
            sh "python E:/airflowtmp/hello.py"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: When I do it the way you say it gives E:\Jenkins\workspace\HelloWorld>python E:/airflowtmp/hello.py 
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Im using windows so I switched sh to bat